# Upload cropped image with Antd in React to Express multer

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, antd, multer

I'm trying to upload a cropped image with Antd upload in React and receive it with multer in express.
I'm appending image to formData then posting it with axios. But the multer field is empty. I didn't face any problem in simple file upload. But can't manage with Antd upload.

Here is my React code:
API is set up axios. It is working everywhere.

```
export default class Upload extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            avatar: [],
            loading: true
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }

onChange(e) {
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('avatar', e.file)
    API.post('/account/avatar', formData, config)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    console.log(e.file)
}

   render() {
        return (
                        <ImgCrop shape='round'>
                            <Upload
                                action={this.onChange}
                                multiple={false}
                                showUploadList='false'
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            >
                                <Button className='upload-avatar-btn'><i className='lnir lnir-pencil'></i></Button>
                            </Upload>
                        </ImgCrop>
       )
}
```

Logging e.file in browser's console is giving this:

```
{lastModifiedDate: 1595920324076, name: "anders-jilden-tcEGBIHm_6E-unsplash.jpg", uid: "rc-upload-1595919951039-2", lastModified: undefined, size: 70585, …}
lastModified: undefined
lastModifiedDate: 1595920324076
name: "anders-jilden-tcEGBIHm_6E-unsplash.jpg"
originFileObj: Blob {lastModifiedDate: 1595920324076, name: "anders-jilden-tcEGBIHm_6E-unsplash.jpg", uid: "rc-upload-1595919951039-2", size: 70585, type: "image/jpeg"}
percent: 100
size: 70585
status: "uploading"
type: "image/jpeg"
uid: "rc-upload-1595919951039-2"
__proto__: Object
```

Express code:

```
.post('/avatar', upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }]), (req, res) => {
    const files = req.files.avatar;
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.files.avatar)
    res.send('Uploaded');
})
```

I'm getting 200 status code in client. But multer is not uploading anything. I have no idea what to do.
`console.log(req.files)` is giving this:

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to wait until upload finished via `e.file.status === 'done'`.

After this you can upload the original file object using `e.file.originFileObj`.

E.g.:

```
onChange(e) {
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('avatar', e.file.originFileObj)
        API.post('/account/avatar', formData, config)
           .then(res => {
               console.log(res.data)
           })
       console.log(e.file)
   }
}
```

This [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epi25?file=/index.js) is good tutorial for using [Antd's Upload](https://ant.design/components/upload/).

For further inspection of your issue you need to post a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e.g. as [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: OK. But it is sending as a blob not as file. And multer is not seeing it as image. How can I send it as simple file not as blob?

Comment: Have a look at the [antd upload docs](https://ant.design/components/upload/). Maybe check `transformFile` or `customRequest`. What format is `simple file`?

Comment: Now I'm using custom request. I mean, even if I upload jpg image it is sending a blob, not jpg file

Comment: The file is sent without extention name. Is there any way to fix it inside beforeUpload functon?

Comment: I'm changing file name while appending it to FormData. Now it works perfect!